# How to enable mod_rewrite in Apache?

Tags: apache2

I just installed the LAMP stack on my Ubuntu system.

The redirection is not working for me. I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: IMHO this question is not Ubuntu specific and should be migrated to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: The OP installed Lamp on UBUNTU. How much more Ubuntu specific do you want?

Comment: @wojov: I don't know about this case, but that argument doesn't work. "How can I use this application (on Ubuntu)?" are mostly off-topic.

Comment: This is not a "How can I use application", but a "how to enable a specific feature in Ubuntu". Apache under Ubuntu uses a different configuration layout in which each module and virtual host is a file in `/etc/apache2` and which can be enabled using `a2*` programs.

Comment: You should describe what you have done to narrow down the problem, it

Answer (score 247):

To enable it the rewrite module, run "apache2 enable module rewrite":

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

You need to restart the webserver to apply the changes:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If you plan on using mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` files, you also need to enable the use of `.htaccess` files by changing `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride FileInfo`. For the default website, edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`:

```
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            # changed from None to FileInfo
            AllowOverride FileInfo
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

After such a change, you need to restart Apache again.

- [Apache documentation on AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride)
- [Manual page of `a2enmod`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man8/a2enmod.8.html)

Comment: I had more success with AllowOverride All

Comment: Thanks! `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and `FileInfo` fixed it for me!

Comment: For me that file was /etc/apache2/apache2.conf where I found that config entry

Comment: Yes make the two changes fixed the problem.

Comment: It is not working for me. I posted a question here http://askubuntu.com/questions/809619/failing-to-rewrite-url

Answer (score 51):

I dare to add a special answer (as a followup to the great answer above) regarding **ubuntu 14.04** and `.htaccess` :

In 14.04, the name of the default configuration file is changed to `000-default.conf` :

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

add the following to the end of the file :

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

For some reason, in Ubuntu 14.04 and apache2 the root is set to `/www/html`. If you want to change the webserver root back to good old `/www`, `open 000-default.conf` and change

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
```

to

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/
```

and then off course it should be

```
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanx for info! This/new way we can use www as folder where we put all websites, and html is by default "website" for localhost. May be important if you are playing with opening ports to world - that this way your localhost cannot see folders of other projects.

Comment: It is not working for me. I am using  `Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS`