# Apache2 server failed to start after enabling `mod_rewrite`, returns "Operation Not Permitted" errors

Tags: permissions, apache2, php, mod-rewrite

I am trying to install `cakephp` ( a php framework) which requires to enable mod_rewrite. For this I followed [Enable mod_rewrite](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48362/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-in-apache) answer. But after restarting my server It says:

```
nitish@nitish-G31T-M7:~$ service apache2 restart

Restarting web server apache2 /usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error
setting limit (Operation not permitted) apache2: Could not reliably
determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1
for ServerName /usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit
(Operation not permitted) apache2: Could not reliably determine the
server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down Unable to open logs

**Action 'start' failed.**

The Apache error log may have more information.
```

What this means? How can I enable `mod_rewrite` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you remember to use `sudo` with the restart command?

If not, you have to have superuser abilities (`sudo`) to restart Apache.  Try using `sudo service apache2 restart` instead.  You need the superuser abilities to shut down the current instance, and then to start up a new one and bind to port 80.

Comment: Oh Thanks @Thomas W. Its starting. But `cakephp` home page still says url is not properly configured `URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server.`.

Comment: @Nitish that's a separate issue.  Your question asks about the restart issue.  I would suggest that you take a look at [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite) by Digital Ocean's comunity that details all the steps to enable mod_rewrite.  YOu also have to set up 'AllowOverride' everywhere rewrite is used to "All" according to multiple online guides about this.  (Please also note I use NGINX as my webserver, not Apache, so beyond the starting-up issue here of you not using sudo, my ability to help with the cakephp issues is limited with Apache)