# .htaccess Apache Mode Rewrite not Working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

New to Ubuntu and trying to set-up PHP environment. Now most of the things are set but .htaccess file not working at all for my CMS.

I have two sites `/var/www/one/` and `/var/www/two/` now when I hit `http://localhost/` it is showing me two directories.

Now when I tried to set `.htacces` to rewrite the URL it is giving me page not found error. I have tried many things but nothing work. Eventually I found this https://askubuntu.com/a/48363/249945 and when I tried it is giving me `Internal Server Error` for the site `one` which has `.htaccess` file.

Please help me to make it work.. Million.. trillion thanks... :)

Forgot to mention when I try to use above answer solution it is hiding my `one` directory if I access `http://localhost/` and showing only directory `two`

Comment: Latest apache version has change in some way. Try this one http://askubuntu.com/questions/423514/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-virtual-host/423589#423589

Comment: Cool resolved.... can you please tell me how can I learn all apache stuffs?

Comment: This is apache official documentation - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html .. But this is more interesting and I learned a lot from here - http://htaccess-guide.com/

Answer (score 0):

Though in comments you said that the proposed workaround solved your issue, I wonder if you have tried to create two different virtual hosts for Apache, so that you can access every folder through different `.local` domains.

For how to create an vhost, this linode guide seems pretty straight-forward

https://www.linode.com/wiki/index.php/Configure_apache_to_use_virtual_hosts_on_ubuntu_server

For how to add any `.local` domains to your hosts file you can edit `/etc/hosts` using gedit or any text editor of your choice.

This post to a Debian mail list a few months ago should guide you to get this working.

https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2013/07/msg00809.html

In this way you will set up a more organized developing environment in your local machine. You may still need mod_rewrite if the webapps/websites you are building require it, but not to prevent the `localhost/one/` ugly url issue.